# What happened to my flag history? Was my flag declined?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

Two days ago I flagged a post. I'm relatively new to the site (54 days) and I'm still getting used to things and I'm afraid I might have improperly flagged the post for moderator review. Maybe I should have just edited the post myself, but it would have involved the removal of *a lot* of text, and I wasn't sure of the protocol. . . anyway, I noticed that my flag weight of 110 disappeared after I flagged the post in question. Did I lose my flag weight because I did something wrong? If so, what do I need to do in the future to prevent this from happening again? I didn't receive any response to my flagging the post, so I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: Try this.  Open [this link](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/flag-weight/3500).  Does that show you a list of items you've flagged?

Comment: There's no such thing as flag weight any more, and flagging works differently these days. Would you mind if I delete this post as no longer relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight) see your flag history from a link in your profile, as soon as you've raised your first flag.

<sub>Formerly, the link to your flag history only appeared when your flag weight was not 100. This was a bug: there was a check in the code that hid the flag weight indication when the flag weight was 100, on the assumption that you'd never flagged, but you could have a flag weight of 100 if you had an equal number of flags marked “helpful” and flags marked “declined”. The bug had been noticed before but for some reason not been reported as such; [I reported it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119127/flag-history-not-shown-in-the-profile-when-the-flag-weight-is-100) (the bug report is now deleted because it is moot).</sub>

<sub>Your flag history is still visible (to you and moderators) if you navigate to the URL by hand: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/flag-weight/3500</sub>

---

I won't go into specifics of your flag history here since this is a public place.

I'll just say that the most common reason for declining flags is when you're asking a moderator to judge whether an answer is correct. Moderators will delete non-answers, i.e. posts that do not address the question at all. But if an answer is wrong, misleading, or badly written (but not completely incomprehensible), but relevant, the proper remedy is for you to edit it to make it correct or downvote it, and preferably leave a comment to educate the poster as to what was wrong.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't be afraid of editing someone else's post to make a minor correction. If the answer is so wrong that you can't correct it without denaturing it, downvote, comment, and write a better answer if you can.

As for flag weight, it's a pretty meaningless number, far more meaningless even than reputation. ([I've in fact argued for its removal, without success.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106614/remove-flag-weight-and-flag-validity-already) Please do continue flagging when you see objectionable behavior (non-answers, offensive content, vandalism, and so on).

Comment: +29/-28, impressive.  I don't think I've seen such a polarizing question before.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the flag probably did get dismissed as unhelpful.

Did your FW go back down to 100? Since I don't see your flag weight, it probably is 100.  Click the number, you can see the history and resolution on each flag (Everyone can see your weight if it's not 100, but only you and mods can see the history).

Potentially relevant posts on MSO:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116804/flag-weight-score-hidden
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight

Comment: Yeah, I can't see my flag weight at all, even when logged in! So I don't know what it is. I'm assuming it's around 100 because I've only twice flagged posts. I have a feeling I improperly flagged the post in question. But what's the community etiquette for editing someone's post and removing large portions of text as subjective/extraneous/tangential?

Comment: @Slytherincess try [this for regular](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/flag-weight/3500) or [this for meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/flag-weight/3500)

Comment: @Slytherincess The purpose of the site is to provide answers for questions, and we are encouraged to improve the quality of the questions *as long as we don't materially change it* or take out things that are likely to lead others with the same question to it.  If removing the information improved its readability without actually changing the question, it's probably fine.

Comment: And if you want me to look at the edit in question and give my opinion and an explanation of the edits, post a link, or create a chatroom if you prefer not calling him/her out in front of everyone.

Comment: Oh, and you have enough rep that if you think the edit really detracts from the question you can revert it, so you should really only flag that sort of thing if it seems to be in bad faith, otherwise just revert.

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't mind your opinion on it. I can pop into chat if you're there. Just let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I'm around, pop into the main chat or create a room if you don't want everyone who happens to be in chat to see.

Comment: Okay, will do. I'll pop into the main chat. Maybe others will have some thoughts too -- it is a community-driven site after all :)